# AngularJS видимость переменной

Tags: angularjs, javascript

Переменная $rootScope.fontSize, имеет данные только в пределах функции then(). Почему я не могу получить ее значение за пределами getCurrentFontSize()?

```
$scope.getCurrentFontSize = function () {
             eventService.GetSettingOverview(internalAuthService.authentication.userProfileData.contextID).then(function (data) {
                 $scope.fontSize = data.data.data.SettingOverview.fontSize;
                 console.log($rootScope.fontSize) // тут все значения есть
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('Error while getting default font size from server');
            });
        };

        $scope.getCurrentFontSize();
        console.log($rootScope.fontSize); // Ничего нету тут
```

Comment: Если представить, что данная функция - это Ajax-запрос, данные в success приходят не сразу, а обработка скрипта продолжается, не дожидаясь этих данных, поэтому, возможно, ничего нет в консоли, потому что запрос ещё не успел выполниться, попробуйте обратиться к переменной за пределами через пару секунд.

Comment: У меня были такие подозрения, а не проверил, зря, да, действительно так и есть. Спасибо!

Comment: насколько я правильно понимаю, в таких случаях используют промисы? (сервис $q)

Answer (score 1):

Promise - это отложенная операция (обещание), которая позволяет писать код лаконично через цепочку вызовов, нежели вкладывать один callback  в другой ("callback callback-ом погоняет") + удобный перехват исключений `.catch()`.

В Вашем случае, можно повестить watch-ер на `$rootScope.fontSize` и ждать пока появится значение:

```
$rootScope.$watch('fontSize', function(value) {
...
});
```